# xampp localhost returns not found for existing file

Tags: xampp

I have a project on local host with a root path

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/myapp/
```

I can open all files in browser by their urls like

```
http://myapp.local/js/app.js
http://myapp.local/js/routes.js
```

the only problem is I can't open any images not while running the project nor when entering their exact url:

```
http://myapp.local/img/logo.png
http://myapp.local/img/loader.gif
```

which return 404 error.
I'm sure those file exist and the path is correct. so why this happens only for files in img folder?
- Also I can't set additional permissions for this folder because all the project will be deleted and created again every time project runs

Comment: Strange! Are you sure it returns 404 error and not 403? Can you also provide your `.htaccess` code? There could be a mod_rewrite code that might be causing this error.

Comment: @NikhilSupekar Yes I'm sure on 404. I didn't figure the issue out but I removed the host entirely and added a new one after a system restart and done! I think it was a silly Windows problem.